# How can we know memory required in executing an method

Tags: java, memory

I want to know how much `memory` is allocated in executing a `method` ..

Is there any `pre-defined` `method` to calculate the `memory` allocated or any process to calculate ...

Note : `Method` may contain any number of lines ...

For Example : To calculate time taken to execute `method` is calcluated by calling `System.currentTimeMillis();` before and after calling the particular `method` . In this way is there any way to calculate `memory` required

Thank You ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a profiler.

They usually offer insights into the heap (and many other interesting things) so you can compare allocations before and after executing a method, which also is the standard approach to finding memory leaks, besides static analysis.

More advanced tools give you more detailed insights and analysis options.

For starters, take a look at visualvm, which comes for free with all current JDKs from Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Runtime.totalMemory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory%28%29) which (per the Javadoc) returns *the total amount of memory in the Java virtual machine.*

```
System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
```

Comment: By Using `System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());` before and after calling the `method` it is returning same number `(517734)` . In my `method` I have an `array` with `10,000` numbers and by `iterating` that `array` i am adding each element to an `ArratList`

Comment: If the array and `ArrayList` aren't referenced after the method completes then they are unreachable and can be garbage collected.

Comment: Now i added the `System.out.println` statements at starting of the method and at the ending of the method ,but the number i getting is same .

Answer (score 0):

Your method will not have a size in java, your objects do.

I suggest use java agent [sizeofag](https://code.google.com/p/sizeofag/). Before calling your method on your object measure your object size, then after calling your method, measure your object size again.See example below.

While calling your program add following line to your java call.

```
-javaagent:sizeofag.jar
```

While your program is running, you can use SizeOfAgent as below.

```
YourObject b = new YourObject();
System.out.println(b + ": " + SizeOfAgent.sizeOf(b));
b.method();
System.out.println(b + ": " + SizeOfAgent.sizeOf(b));
```